# update the value of an empty attribute class using a method

Tags: python, class, attributes

Does anyone know how to update the value of an empty class instance in a method? My code does not work as expected.

```
class addition:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = None
    def add(self, data):
        
        if self.number == None:
            print('no')
            self.number = data
        else:
            print('yes')
            self.number + 10
        return self.number 

addition().add(4)
addition().add(5)
```

With addition().add(5) I want self.number to be equal to 4 but it stays equal to none. Please help!

Comment: `addition()` creates a new instance, and immediately calls `.add()` - but the instance is not stored anywhere. What did you expect?

Comment: @Marat This is what I expected: "With addition().add(5) I want self.number to be equal to 4 but it stays equal to none"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either **instantiate an object** of your class or use a **class method**.

When you use a non static class, the members of your class receive the self identifier, meaning that they belong to that specific instance, that needs to be created. Like:

```py
class addition:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = None
    def add(self, data):
        
        if self.number == None:
            print('no')
            self.number = data
        else:
            print('yes')
            self.number + 10
        return self.number 

addition1 = addition()
addition1.add(4)
addition1.add(5)
```

Otherwise, you can use a variable as a member of the class itself and declare the method a **class method**, then you don't need to instantiate an object and can call it directly. With a class method you don't use the word **self**, because you don't have an instance. Instead, you use (by convention) the word **cls**, referring to the class. Example:

```py
class addition:
    number = None
    
    @classmethod    
    def add(cls, data):
        
        if cls.number == None:
            print('no')
            cls.number = data
        else:
            print('yes')
            cls.number + 10
        return cls.number 

addition.add(4)
addition.add(5)
```

Comment: `self` is not a keyword in Python, like `this` in JavaScript. It's just a convention. You could initialize the class with `def __init__(bacon_sausage_spam):` and then just use `bacon_sausage_spam.number = None`. It's slightly longer and annoying to write, but it works.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Thanks for make it clear! I said that about the word 'cls' but don't about 'this'.